# zotero not working with libreoffice 4.3 in linux mint 16

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, zotero

As title, I tried to use zotero in libreoffice, after I installed zotero, I found from zotero's preference that the add-in was not installed, I click the button to install but nothing happen. I googled a while but still cannot find way to solve it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There are some other issues with 4.3 as well. It messed up tracked changes in a doc file. I guess it is better to downgrade to 4.2.6-secfix

Answer (score 0):

Anyways just try ths:

Enable java in libreoffice: `Tools -> options -> Advanced -> use JRE`

Then go to `libreoffice -> tools -> extenstion manager -> Add`

Select `<Zotero-folder>/extensions/zoteroOpenOfficeIntegration@zotero.org/install/`

Restart libreoffice